# Benchmark for cache-to-cache latency

Tags: benchmarking, intel, amd-processor

I'm looking for a benchmark that can measure the cache latencies and bandwidth of the processors. In particular I need the measurement for cache-to-cache times from one core to another (including different die and different socket).

Something which runs on linux is required.

A web page showing the results of such tests on the most recent CPUs would also be a good compromise for now.

Answer (score 3):

Try lmbench3, it has all kind of benchmarks including the ones you want